# Algorithm for Removing Outliers from a dataset of prices

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, statistics

This is kind of a neat problem and I've enjoyed thinking it through...

Assume that you run a "Widget Rental" website, and on your application and you want to allow prospective purchasers to sort the widgets based on prices. (Low to high or high to low).

Each widget can have a different price based on the time of year. Some widgets will have dozens of different prices depending on the season as you get "high" seasons and "low" seasons.

However, the sellers of the "Widgets" are **especially mischievous**, and have realised that if they set their widget to be really expensive for one day of the year, and also really cheap one day of the year, then they can easily appear at the low and high sort ranges.

Currently, I took a very naive solution in order to calculate the "lowest price" for a Widget, which is to just take the `lowest( N )` value from a dataset.

What I would like to is to get a "lowest from price" for a widget, which accurately portrays the price which it could be rented from.. and remove the lower/higher-band outliers.

Take a look at this chart... with values...

[image: Chart]

> X Axis - Time (each significant interval is a day)
>
> Y Axis - Price

The X axis is time, and the Y axis is the price. Now, this contains a normal distribution, and there aren't any real statistical outliers in that dataset. It's common to see the price between the lowest value and the upper value to fluctuate as much as 200%.

However, take a look at this second chart... It contains a single day tariff, which is only 20 ēuros...

[image]

I've played around with using Grubbs test and it seems to work quite well.

The important thing is that I want to get a "from price". That is to say, I want to be able to say, "You can rent this widget from XXXX". So it should be reflect the overall pricing taken as a whole and ignore clear outliers.

PHP bonus points if you point me in the direction of anything that already exists. (But I'm happy to code this myself in PHP).

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that there are multiple definitions for what an [outlier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier#Identifying_outliers) actually is. However, for this purpose a straight forward solution seems sufficient.

You could remove outliers by limiting the range of values to either +- some percentage or +- some number of standard deviations (probably one or two, but it could [very](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Chebyshev.27s_inequality)) from the average price. Likely you'd probably want to use a combination of both, as if the prices don't very much, then a discount could be viewed as an outlier, which may or may not be appropriate. In any case, you'd likely have to do some experimenting to determine how sensitive it is. Chances are you'd probably want to set it so outliers must be at least some percentage away from the mean even if it's only 5-20 percent. Below are a few percentage based limits based on an average of $500.

- 90%: $50  to $950
- 75%: $125 to $875
- 50%: $250 to $750
- 30%: $350 to $650
- 25%: $375 to $650

If multiple passes are used, then it would be easier to sort the prices, then remove the price that is farthest from the average (perhaps considering the highest price as well as the lowest price) as long as it exceeds the range. This ends up being O(N*D log D) to obtain the result of continuous single passes until they have no effect, instead of O(N*D) for a single pass, where N is the number of items to rent and D is the number of days considered.

You also might find the [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) useful for finding points of interest after a bit of experimenting with how to define the value of epsilon.

Comment: Yeah. You are mostly correct about the "from [price]" should be the lowest price, however practically, when you look at some of the Widget rental prices, you can see that some users are intentionally trying to game the sorting by wickedly picking single date (or short regions) and picking really small prices...

These low price outliers aren't genuine basically...

Comment: In that case, you're probably looking at sorting the prices then using some criterion to limit the range of values. I originally avoided going in this direction as the criterion can be fairly arbitrary. This is especially true when you consider discounted, sometimes deeply discounted, prices. I'll change my answer to reflect this.